# How to add dependency reside outside of project in gradle?

Tags: gradle, classpath

I want to include a local jar resides outside my gradle project, how can I do it? Is it possible to use absolute path of the jar file?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies

You can simply add something like

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/local-dependency.jar', 'libs/another.jar')
}
```